# The getter 'documents' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I'm using flutter and firebase to make a to-do list. It keeps showing me this error even after I checked if my **snap.data == null** .But I am not sure why still doesn't work.

please help. I have checked similar problems like this but still didn't solve
sorry for my English

```
 body: StreamBuilder(
 
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("MyTodos").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshots) {
        return ListView.builder(
   
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: snapshots.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                snapshots.data.documents[index];
            return Dismissible(
              key: Key(index.toString()),
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(documentSnapshot["todoTitle"]),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        todos.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    )
```

Comment: Have you checked the connectionState ?

Comment: No, How can I do this?

Comment: I guess you already found your answer. But I'm gonna leave it for reference [AsyncSnapshot](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html)

Comment: thanks for mention it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamBuilder` has a default state before it gets any data at all, and you need to check for this state so you don't try to build using data that doesn't exist yet. You can do this by checking either `snapshots.hasData` or `snapshots.data == null`:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  ...
  builder: (context, snapshots) {
    if (!snapshots.hasData) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    else {
      return ListView.builder(
        ...
      );
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: thank you very much the error removed. It seems I forget to put else in the code . I can't put this as the answer because my reputation still low than 15.

Comment: @nadacoco If this answer helped, please consider marking it as correct so that future users with the same question can more easily find it. :)

Comment: I marked it . But still, when I enter my data it doesn't show my todo.

Comment: @nadacoco Then that is probably a separate issue. I'd recommend trying to pinpoint the cause and, if needed, start a new question about that.

Comment: thanks for caring I fixed it by flutter run in the terminal.